# I keep getting this error message unreachable code, why is that? Here si my code

Tags: java

I keep getting the error message in Java unreachable code. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int product;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Factorial Calculator!");

        Object response;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer that's greater than 0 but less than 10:");
            n = input.nextInt();
            product = fact(n);
            System.out.println("The factorial of " + n);
            System.out.println("is " + product);
            System.out.print("Continue?(y/n): ");
            response = input.next();
        } while (response.equals("y") || response.equals("Y"));
    }

    public static int fact(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return n * fact(n - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int result = result * i;
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            if (random > 10) {
                System.out.println("invalid value - continue loop!");
                continue;
                // continue executing loop until the application ends
            }

            System.out.println(random);
        }
    }
}
} // This curly brace is where I keep getting the error code
```

Comment: You have a `for` loop following an `if-else` where both return. That `for` loop is unreachable. Should it be in another method?

Comment: You have an extra `}`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the function fact(int n). You start out with an if statement - you say that if n equals 1, then return 1, else return n*fact(n-1). This is a good recursive function with a base case and a recursive case, but you have code below it that will never get executed because all conditions have already been accounted for. Either n is equal to one, or it isn't!